# How can I solve padding problem with Iframes?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a responsive iframe. I added the `padding-bottom: 56.25%` and `witdh/height: 100%`.I don't want it to fit all the screen because it's too big, so I put `width/height: 75%`. The problem comes here: it creates an empty space under the iframe where I can't put anything. How can I solve it?

```
    <div class="container">
      <iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/cZ_eoZdxv_Q" class="responsive-iframe"
       frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; clipboard-write; encrypted-media;
        gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
```

```
.container
{
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-bottom: 56.25%;
  height: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container iframe
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 75%;
  height: 75%;
}
```

Comment: `padding` is a an extra space **within** the selected element. `margin` is a space **out** of the selected element. The question is: Why you need that space (`padding-bottom: 56.25%;`)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the aspect ratio of the video the white space cannot be removed, otherwise you would see the black space of the player. (like in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-sanderson-l2eyr) that I've made).

My advice is to center the video so the spaces above and below will be equal.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot. I will use your code because I don't really care about that black layer.